# Python: return a range given two multi-character strings

Tags: python

Looking for help writing a function to do the following:

Input:
two multi-character strings like "AA" and "AD"

Output:
a range from the first multi-character string to the secnod.  Ex: "AA" "AD" should return "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD 
also the function should wrap around the alphabet as well, so "AZ" "BB" would yield "AZ" "BA" "BB"

Ive tried:

```
import string

alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
racks = list([i+b for i in alphabet for b in alphabet])

rn = 1
for rack in racks:
    print(rack)
    rn = rn + 1
```

but this gives every multiline string AA-ZZ.  I want the user to be able to specify where the last string should end

Comment: And did you try anything?

Comment: what "should"?.

Comment: hey sorry the original post was vague. I have updated =)

Comment: It's unfortunate that you took so long to add your own code, so that your question was closed. I have voted to reopen it, now that you have added your own code attempt, but that may take a while. But here is one idea. Use two nested loops. The outer loop runs from the first character in the first input string up to (and including) the first character in the second input string. This loop character is the first character in the output string. For each of these loop characters, set the lower and upper limits for the second character in the output string...

Comment: ... Each limit setting uses an `if` statement which looks if the first output char equals the first input char (for the lower limit) or second input char (for the upper limit). Then use those limits to loop over that second output character and build the full output string for that iteration of the inner loop. Is that idea clear? The code is easier than the explanation.

Comment: You can kludge it with a condition on your nested comprehension.  Let `last` be your end point, such as `last = "Bf".lower()`.  Now append a check to your comprehension:  `list([i+b for i in alphabet for b in alphabet if i+b <= last])`

Comment: Another idea is to find the conversion functions from two-character strings to integers and back. `'AA'` goes to `0` and vice versa, etc. Then convert the two input strings to integers, loop on an integer between those two integers, and convert that integer to a two-character string. The conversion functions are pretty simple--you should be able to figure them out.

Answer (score 1):

The most general solution, I think, involves converting the letters to and from serial numbers:

```
ALPHABET = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'  
#ALPHABET = 'BCXYZ'   # you can define/restrict the symbol set any way you like
LOOKUP = { letter.upper() : i for i, letter in enumerate( ALPHABET ) }
BASE = len( ALPHABET )

def l2n(letters):
    "Convert a letter code to a serial number"
    return sum(LOOKUP[ch] * BASE ** i for i, ch in enumerate(letters[::-1].upper()))

def n2l(number, minlength=2 ):
    "Convert a serial number to a letter code"
    letters = ''
    while True:
        letters += ALPHABET[number % BASE]
        number //= BASE
        if not number and len(letters) >= minlength:
            return letters[::-1]

def sequence(first, last, minlength=None):
    """
    Generator function for letter codes (each
    at least `minlength` characters long) from
    `first` to `last` inclusive.
    """
    if minlength is None:
        minlength = min(len(first), len(last))
    for i in range(l2n(first), l2n(last) + 1):
        yield n2l(i, minlength)

# example 1
print(list(sequence('BB', 'CZ')))


# example 2 - use the generator to start anywhere and
# produce any length of sequence, without excessive
# demands on memory:
for code in sequence('XYZZY', 'ZZYZX'):
    print(code)
```